# An Adjective Describing the Sound of Someone Losing Her Voice?

Tags: single-word-requests

Notice I said "losing," not "lost." I need an adjective for a voice with a several cracks here and there, like Emma Stone, Lindsay Lohan, or Scarlett Johansson's, but a little more dire. I want something that sounds "cute," though. Not the sound, but the word.

"Raspy" sounds harsh and unattractive for my female character, and so does "hoarse." "Husky" is geared more toward guys than girls. In my novel, she actually is losing her voice, so if you'd like to contribute, please do.

I'm not sure if an example sentence is truly necessary, as I've already provided the context needed.

Comment: "Husky" can be used for females, I don't think you should dismiss it out-of-hand.

Comment: If you want a term for a voice with "cracks", what's wrong with "cracking"?

Comment: @HotLicks - Good word but could be a little tricky to use in a sentence.  Can you give some examples?  For example, as an article title, "Emma Stone explains how she came to have a cracking voice" doesn't quite work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not as concerned about the word *raspy* as you are.  However, you can also consider

> ragged
>
> scratchy
>
> rough

If it's okay to use more than one word:

> delicately hoarse
>
> slightly raspy
>
> has a slight rasp
>
> voice cracks occasionally (as you said in your question)

Possibly related:

> [vocal fry](http://www.ohniww.org/katy-perry-voice-vocal-fry/)

I looked for articles about Emma Stone's voice, and found "husky," "somewhat gritty" and "husky, sexy."

And I support "throaty" as proposed by Saubree.

Helpful photographs and diagrams of "singer's nodules," and treatments, can be found at http://www.fauquierent.net/vocalcordnodule.htm.

Stone speaks about her treatment, and Meryl Streep's advice to her to use her rasp to her advantage: http://www.instyle.com/videos/what-happened-when-emma-stone-lost-her-voice-front-meryl-streep

An ENT's analysis of Lindsay Lohan's voice: http://www.ohniww.org/lindsay-lohan-emma-stone-voice-preservation/

Answer (score 1):

"Stark" as in rigid.
"thickly" means with a low voice that comes mostly from your throat. 
"throaty" the sound is low ans seems to come from deep in your throat. 
"gravelly" or "gruff" these voices have a rough low sound. 
"croaky" if someones voice sounds croaky, they speak in a low rough voice that sounds as if they have a sore throat.
"sotto voce" in a very quiet voice.